# Trouble with Raspberry Pi 3 B+, ONOFF (Node) and Sparkfun Large Digit Driver

Tags: javascript, raspberry-pi, binary, gpio, serial-communication

I'm not able to get the attached Javascript code to properly control my 7-segment Large Digit Driver from Sparkfun. However the nearly identical code in Python works great. Seems like it must be something to do with the way the GPIO library (onoff) in Node is driving the GPIO ports because changing the settings changes the behavior, but not successfully.

```js
// GUIDE FOR RASPBERRY PI
// https://medium.com/@jonah.lefkoff/how-to-hook-up-the-sparkfun-7-segment-display-to-a-raspberry-pi-577591ba94b5


console.log("STARTING CLOCK")

// Ability to shut down
const child_process = require("child_process")
process.on('SIGINT', () => {
    clock.unexport()
    latch.unexport()
    data.unexport()
})

// Load GPIO library onoff
let GPIO = require('onoff').Gpio

// Number of display digits that are physically wired up
const DIGITS = 1


// Set everything to LOW
let latch = new GPIO(17, 'low', 'rising', { activeLow: false })
let clock = new GPIO(27, 'low', 'rising', { activeLow: false })
let data = new GPIO(22, 'low', 'rising', { activeLow: false })


function postNumber(num, decimal) {
    let a = 1 << 0
    let b = 1 << 6
    let c = 1 << 5
    let d = 1 << 4
    let e = 1 << 3
    let f = 1 << 1
    let g = 1 << 2
    let dp = 1 << 7
    let segments

    switch (num) {
        case 1: segments = b | c; break;
        case 2: segments = a | b | d | e | g; break;
        case 3: segments = a | b | c | d | g; break;
        case 4: segments = b | c | f | g; break;
        case 5: segments = a | c | d | f | g; break;
        case 6: segments = a | c | d | e | f | g; break;
        case 7: segments = a | b | c; break;
        case 8: segments = a | b | c | d | e | f | g; break;
        case 9: segments = a | b | c | d | f | g; break;
        case 0: segments = a | b | c | d | e | f; break;
        case 'c': segments = d | e | g; break;
        case '-': segments = g; break;
        case ' ': segments = 0; break;
        default: segments = 0; break;
    }

    //if (decimal) segments = segments | dp

    console.log(num, segments.toString(2), segments)

    for (let y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
        clock.writeSync(GPIO.LOW)
        data.writeSync(segments & 1 << (7 - y))
        clock.writeSync(GPIO.HIGH)
    }

}



function showNumber(val) {
    let num = Math.abs(val) // remove any signs
    for (let x = 1; x <= DIGITS; x++) {
        let remainder = parseInt(num % 10) //the remainder is what needs to be posted to each digit
        postNumber(remainder, false)
        num /= 10
    }

    latch.writeSync(GPIO.LOW)
    latch.writeSync(GPIO.HIGH)
}


for (let x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    showNumber(x)
    child_process.execSync("sleep .5")
}
```

[image: Wiring Setup]

FWIW, the following Python code DOES work:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env python
#By Jonah
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
from time import sleep
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
segmentLatch=11
segmentClock=13
segmentData=15
GPIO.setup(segmentClock,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(segmentData,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(segmentLatch,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(segmentClock,GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(segmentData,GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(segmentLatch,GPIO.LOW)
number=0
DIGITS = 1
#Takes a number and displays 2 numbers. Display absolute value (no negatives)
#look here maybe bug between value+number
def showNumber(value):
        number = abs(value) #Remove negative signs and any decimals
        x=0
        while(x < DIGITS):
                remainder=number % 10
                postNumber(remainder)
                number /= 10
                x += 1
#Latch the current segment data
        GPIO.output(segmentLatch,GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(segmentLatch,GPIO.HIGH) #Register moves storage register on the rising edge of RCK
#Given a number, or - shifts it out to the display
def postNumber(number):
    a=1<<0
    b=1<<6
    c=1<<5
    d=1<<4
    e=1<<3
    f=1<<1
    g=1<<2
    dp=1<<7

    if   number == 1: segments =     b | c
    elif number == 2: segments = a | b |     d | e |     g
    elif number == 3: segments = a | b | c | d |         g
    elif number == 4: segments =     b | c |         f | g
    elif number == 5: segments = a |     c | d     | f | g
    elif number == 6: segments = a |     c | d | e | f | g
    elif number == 7: segments = a | b | c
    elif number == 8: segments = a | b | c | d | e | f | g
    elif number == 9: segments = a | b | c | d     | f | g
    elif number == 0: segments = a | b | c | d | e | f
    elif number == ' ': segments = 0
    elif number == 'c': segments = g | e | d
    elif number == '-': segments = g
    else : segments = False

    #if (segments != dp):
    print (number, "{0:b}".format(segments), segments)

    y=0
    while(y<8):
        GPIO.output(segmentClock,GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(segmentData,segments & 1 << (7-y))
        GPIO.output(segmentClock,GPIO.HIGH)
        y += 1

x=0
while(x < 10):
        showNumber(x)
        x += 1
        sleep(0.2)

GPIO.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out but I don't understand it completely yet...

With the Javascript library (onoff), the bits are being shifted in with the same order. However, they're being registered backwards. The solution was to modify the code to reverse the order of bits being shifted in to the register before latching. Here is the working javascript code...

```js
// GUIDE FOR RASPBERRY PI
// https://medium.com/@jonah.lefkoff/how-to-hook-up-the-sparkfun-7-segment-display-to-a-raspberry-pi-577591ba94b5


console.log("STARTING CLOCK")

// Ability to shut down
const child_process = require("child_process")
process.on('SIGINT', () => {
    clock.unexport()
    latch.unexport()
    data.unexport()
})

// Load GPIO library onoff
let GPIO = require('onoff').Gpio

// Number of display digits that are physically wired up
const DIGITS = 1


// Set everything to LOW
let latch = new GPIO(17, 'out')
let clock = new GPIO(27, 'out')
let data = new GPIO(22, 'out')


function postNumber(num, decimal) {
    let a = 1 << 0 //00000001
    let b = 1 << 6 //01000000
    let c = 1 << 5 //00100000
    let d = 1 << 4 //00010000
    let e = 1 << 3 //00001000
    let f = 1 << 1 //00000010
    let g = 1 << 2 //00000100
    let p = 1 << 7 //10000000
    let segments = false

    switch (num) {
        case 1: segments = b | c; break;
        case 2: segments = a | b | d | e | g; break;
        case 3: segments = a | b | c | d | g; break;
        case 4: segments = b | c | f | g; break;
        case 5: segments = a | c | d | f | g; break;
        case 6: segments = a | c | d | e | f | g; break;
        case 7: segments = a | b | c; break;
        case 8: segments = a | b | c | d | e | f | g; break;
        case 9: segments = a | b | c | d | f | g; break;
        case 0: segments = a | b | c | d | e | f; break;
        default: break;
    }

    console.log('segments', segments, segments.toString(2))

    //if (decimal) segments = segments | p

    latch.writeSync(GPIO.LOW)
    for (let y = 8; y > 0; y--) {
        let shift = (segments >> y - 1) & 1
        clock.writeSync(GPIO.LOW)
        data.writeSync(shift)
        console.log('shift', shift)
        clock.writeSync(GPIO.HIGH)
    }
    latch.writeSync(GPIO.HIGH)

}



function showNumber(val) {
    let num = Math.abs(val) // remove any signs
    for (let x = 1; x <= DIGITS; x++) {
        let remainder = parseInt(num % 10) //the remainder is what needs to be posted to each digit
        postNumber(remainder, false)
        num /= 10
    }
}

for (let x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    showNumber(x)
    child_process.execSync("sleep .1")
}
```